# How do you use different @font-face styles?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am writing in an app that already has a bunch of @font-face styles defined so I need to use them.  But I do not see how to use them as I don't see how they have separate or different names... its just @font-face repeatedly.  How would I choose one of these?  I want the one with the font-weight of 800.

```
$font-name: 'Open Sans';
$font-dir: 'OpenSans';

@font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src:
        local('☺'),
        url('Open_Sans_300.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Open_Sans_300.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src:
        local('☺'),
        url('Open_Sans_400.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Open_Sans_400.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src:
        local('☺'),
        url('Open_Sans_600.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Open_Sans_600.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src:
        local('☺'),
        url('Open_Sans_700.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Open_Sans_700.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    src:
        local('☺'),
        url('Open_Sans_800.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Open_Sans_800.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much like the `@font-face` declarations, you simply need to set a `font-weight` CSS property on the element that's referencing the font. Note that while this is typically used for `normal` or `bold`, you can also specify the integer value:

```
element {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 300; // Will use 'Open_Sans_300.woff'
}

element2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400; // Will use 'Open_Sans_400.woff'
}
```

Comment: I can't I'm only able to use pre-defined classes and whatever else is in our styles folder.  I can't add any custom styling.  What I pasted above is an entire file.  But I don't know how to reference any of them in my html... do you know how to do that?

Comment: You could use inline styles, which is essentially the same thing. Something like `<div style="font-family: 'CustomFont'; font-weight: 400;">`.

Comment: No I'm not allowed to do that either.  I'm only allowed to apply existing styles such as a class name to an element.  I don't understand what the point of this file is if I can't use it without doing custom styles...

Comment: Is there another way to trigger these @font-face font-weight properties??

Comment: You can use the classname like specified in the answer above. e.g `<div class='element2'>`